# Использование переводчика в приложении

Tags: swift

Кто сталкивался с переводчиками? Есть ли бесплатные переводчики?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть API от основных интернет-гигантов google & yandex.

[Yandex translate API](https://tech.yandex.com/translate/) позволяет бесплатно переводить определенное число символов в месяц, при превышении лимита начинает брать за это деньги. Для использования требуется создать аккаунт и сгенерировать нужный ключ. Т.к кошелек для оплаты будет привязан к аккаунту по факту получится, что вы можете использовать API не имея средств на счету, при превышении лимита API будет возвращать ошибку.

Фактически это значит, что вы можете создать демо-приложение с этим API на "попробовать", просто чтобы посмотреть, как это работает, но в коммерческом приложении вам уже надо будет два раза подумать, прежде чем использовать этот API. (приложение может банально не окупиться)

Примерное то же само относится и к [Google transalte API](https://cloud.google.com/translate/pricing)

Я с google translate API не работал, так что ничего конкретного сказать не могу.

Comment: В google translate API можно бесплатно переводить 2 млн. символов в сутки. Кроме того, на первый год даются бесплатные $200 (не уверен в сумме) которые можно потратить на перевод.